# Increase the size of the circle in the following list of references

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \makeatletter
    \def\@biblabel#1{\textcircled{\scriptsize #1}}
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

    \end{thebibliography}
    \end{document}
```

If the list of references exceeds 10, it may not appear aesthetically pleasing. How can I increase the size of the circle?

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers

Comment: @KennethOdle I used this ```\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}``` but the same problem happens

Comment: I will be gretful if you help me

Comment: Change `inner sep` to have a bigger padding between number and circle. Use `text width=width("00"), align=right` to have a circle that fits a two-digit number even if the content is only one-digit. Use the [`rounded rectangle`](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.rounded:rectangle) to achieve something similar to Sam's answer with TikZ. Though, `circledsteps` is the preferred solution because it's a lighter approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `circledsteps` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circledsteps}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{{\scriptsize\CircledText{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.
\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.
\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.
\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.

\bibitem{Naj} H. Najafi, Some numerical radius inequality for several operators, Linear Algebra Appl. 588 (2020) 489-496.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to see you. I sended you some emails but I don't receive your response.

Comment: @Student You're welcome! I did not receive any emails. When did you sent them?

Comment: I send you now an email

Comment: @Student Thanks! Finally found it and replied. Very sorry for the technical problems!