# Custom non-sequential enumeration

Tags: enumitem

I would like to have my `\item` enumerated in a special order, non-sequential. In the example below (which is my current project) there are always exactly 3 `\item`s.

(To handle user errors where the `\item` counter exceeds the defined maximal number, it could output a (red) error text for the `\item`(s), to draw attention that the enumeration list contains too many `\item`s.)

[image]

In this case I have used code for circled text from [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)

I would like to type

```
\begin{CircleProcedure}
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{CircleProcedure}
```

instead of the 'full' argument as shown in the MWE below.

Another possible output that I'm thinking of is with a mathematical index, shown as sample No. 2

Below I show a suggested input in an MWE, but with the `[]` arguments that I would like to avoid.

(For simple and uniform input/output environments are used)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\newenvironment{CircleProcedure}
    {\begin{enumerate}[labelwidth=16mm,leftmargin=16mm,labelsep=2mm]}
    {\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{IndexProcedure}
    {\begin{enumerate}[align=left,labelwidth=9mm,leftmargin=10mm,labelsep=1mm]}
    {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{CircleProcedure}
\item[\circled{1}] \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item[\circled{2}] \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item[\(\circled{1}+\circled{2}\)] \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{CircleProcedure}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
 
\begin{IndexProcedure}
\item[\(\textbf{P}_{1}\)] \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item[\(\textbf{P}_{2}\)] \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item[\(\textbf{P}_{1+2}\)] \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{IndexProcedure}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\end{document}
```

(I run pdfLaTeX 2023 on [overleaf.com](http://www.overleaf.com))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate your own list and then specify the counters should be represented and link the two (using `\AddEnumerateCounter`). The counter representations defines what the numbers look like for 1, 2 and 3, and causes an error ("Counter too large") for `\item` 4 (or higher).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\circled}{m}{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\newlist{CircleProcedure}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[CircleProcedure]{%
  labelwidth=16mm,
  leftmargin=16mm,
  labelsep=2mm,
  label=\circledenum*,
}
\newlist{IndexProcedure}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[IndexProcedure]{%
  align=left,
  labelwidth=15mm,
  leftmargin=15mm,
  labelsep=0mm,
  label=\indexenum*
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\circledenum}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@circledenum\csname c@#1\endcsname%
}
\newcommand*{\@circledenum}[1]{%
  $\ifcase#1\or\circled{1}\or\circled{2}\or\circled{1}+\circled{2}%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi$%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\circledenum}{\@circledenum}{1}

\newcommand*{\indexenum}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@indexenum\csname c@#1\endcsname%
}
\newcommand*{\@indexenum}[1]{%
  $\ifcase#1\or\textbf{P}_1\or\textbf{P}_2\or\textbf{P}_1+\textbf{P}_2%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi$%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\indexenum}{\@indexenum}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{CircleProcedure}
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{CircleProcedure}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{IndexProcedure}
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{IndexProcedure}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\end{document}
```

You can also use `\label` and `\ref` if needed.

Answer (score 4):

One method without using `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\newcounter{CircledProcedure}
\newenvironment{CircledProcedure}%
  {\begin{list}{}{
    \labelwidth 16mm%
    \leftmargin 16mm%
    \labelsep 2mm%
    \let\makelabel\CircledProcedureLabel
    \usecounter{CircledProcedure}
  }}{\end{list}}
\newcommand*{\CircledProcedureLabel}{%
  \ifnum\value{CircledProcedure}<3 \hfill\circled{\theCircledProcedure} \else \(\circled{1}+\circled{2}\) \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{CircledProcedure}
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{CircledProcedure}

\end{document}
```

[image]