How to align the math symbol with regular text in tikz figure in a rectangular node?
I want to draw the figure whose code is produced below in TiKz. As you can see, the eta symbol is not properly aligned with the text "ADD." Please help me to align the text correctly. Also, suggestions for improving the code are welcome. Here is the code.

\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%define the styles below for rectangular and circular node
        [circular/.style={circle,draw=red!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
            inner sep=0pt},>={Stealth},
        transition/.style={rectangle,draw=red!50,fill=cyan!40,thick,
            inner sep=2pt,node distance=0.5,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.85cm,rounded corners}]
        %/      \node [circular,] {content};    
        \node[circular,node font=\Huge]     (addition)      {+};
                
        % node with dummy text
        \node [circular,minimum width=0.85,minimum height=0.85] (multiply1) [left= of addition] {\textcolor{blue!20}{Hello}};
        \path (multiply1.north west) edge[thick] (multiply1.south east);
        \path (multiply1.north east) edge[thick] (multiply1.south west);
        \node[rotate=90]        (layerscale)        [left=of multiply1]     {};
        \path (layerscale.south) ++(0,-0.2) node[rotate=90] {};
        
        \node[transition]       (ffn)       [below=of multiply1]    {$\eta *$ ADD};
        \node[transition]       (eta1)      [below=of ffn]  {$\Omega(\cdot)$};
        \path (multiply1.east)      edge[post,thick]    (addition.west);
        \path (ffn.north)           edge[post,thick]    (multiply1.south);
        \path (eta1.north)          edge[post,thick]    (ffn.south);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

perhaps I was not clear to convey my answer. I have drawn help lines and an additional nodes below the "plus" node containing text "\eta". You can see that two baselines of these two \eta are different.
here is the code
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary {calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{terminal/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,
        % The rest
        very thick,draw=black!50,
        top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
        font=\ttfamily}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%define the styles below for rectangular and circular node
        [circular/.style={circle,draw=red!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
            inner sep=0pt},>={Stealth},
        transition/.style={rectangle,draw=red!50,fill=cyan!40,thick,
            inner sep=2pt,node distance=0.5,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.85cm,rounded corners}]
        %/      \node [circular,] {content};    
        \node[circular,node font=\Huge]     (addition)      {+};
                
        % node with dummy text
        \node [circular,minimum width=0.85,minimum height=0.85] (multiply1) [left= of addition] {\textcolor{blue!20}{Hello}};
        \path (multiply1.north west) edge[thick] (multiply1.south east);
        \path (multiply1.north east) edge[thick] (multiply1.south west);
        \node[rotate=90]        (layerscale)        [left=of multiply1]     {};
        \path (layerscale.south) ++(0,-0.2) node[rotate=90] {};
        
%       \node[transition]       (ffn)       [below=of multiply1]    {$ \eta $*\text{ADD}};
        \node[transition]       (ffn)       [below=of multiply1]    {$\eta  MHTA$};
        \node[transition]  (dummy2) [right=of ffn] {$\eta$} ;
        
         \draw [help lines] let \p1 = (ffn.base),
        \p2 = (dummy2.base),
        in (1.5,\y1) -- (-3,\y1)
        (1.5,\y2) -- (-3,\y2);
        
        \node[transition,baseline=(eta1.base)]          (eta1)      [below=of ffn]  {$\Omega(\cdot)$};
        \path (multiply1.east)      edge[post,thick]    (addition.west);
        \path (ffn.north)           edge[post,thick]    (multiply1.south);
        \path (eta1.north)          edge[post,thick]    (ffn.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


However if I add some text in the \eta box the same problem as previous appears. Please help me out. There is a related question: Good way to make \textcircled numbers?, but it does not solve my problem.

Hi, welcome! What do you mean with "not aligned"? It seems perfect to me (eta has descenders, like for example a "p", and it's lowercase...). Substitute the eta with a "p"or "j" and see...

I think this is fixable. But I am not sure, how it should look like at the end.
a) Is it just about vertical alignment? b) Is it about horizontal alignment? What does the star mean at \eta*; is it something like \eta^*; or
should it be something like \eta <operation> ADD? Or...?
The best would be: try to show - graphically - how it should look like at the end.

@Rmano, I want to align them horizontally; as you can see in the below rectangle, $\Omega(\cdot)$ is perfectly horizontally aligned to the centre line.

Just try sth. like $\eta*\mathrm{ADD}$ or $\eta*\text{ADD}$ and load the amsmath-package.

Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

@VivekHarshey If you want the same alignment irregardless of ascending or descending letters, you can add \strut (or \mathstrut if you are inside math) to your node text: \node[transition]       (ffn)       [below=of multiply1]    {$\mathstrut\eta  MHTA$};         \node[transition]  (dummy2) [right=of ffn] {$\mathstrut\eta$} ; https://i.sstatic.net/oTtOudrA.png

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added the screenshots showing the different alignments. There is a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers/7045#7045, but it does not solve my problem.

So does adding a strut solve your problem?

you could also set the height and depth of the nodes, see end of section "5.1 Styling the Nodes" of the tikz user manual.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, no, unfortunately, adding strut did not solve my problem. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

@VivekHarshey Please explain what alignment is missing after using strut. https://i.sstatic.net/oTtOudrA.png looks pretty much aligned.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, here is an ugly hack that produced the same effect using the following more than one node.
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {inner sep=0pt},transition/.style={rectangle,draw=red!50,fill=cyan!40,thick,
inner sep=2pt,node distance=0.5,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.85cm,rounded corners}]
\node (E) at (0,0) {};
\node (p) [right = 0pt of E,xshift=0.5cm] {MHTA};
\node[] (p1) at (p.center){};
\node (d) [right= -0.95cm of p1] {$\eta*$};
\draw[transition,opacity=0.5] (0,0) ++(0.05,-0.4)rectangle ++(1.6cm,0.85cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You get alignment if you add a strut to both texts, ensuring that the vertical centering is with respect to the strut and not the “height plus depth” of tha actual entries:
        \node[transition] (ffn) [below=of multiply1]    {\strut$\eta  MHTA$};
        \node[transition] (dummy2) [right=of ffn] {\strut$\eta$} ;

All the rest is unchanged.


TikZ way setting text depth and text height.
No hacking, no \strutting.
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary {calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{terminal/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,
        % The rest
        very thick,draw=black!50,
        top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
        font=\ttfamily}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%define the styles below for rectangular and circular node
        [circular/.style={circle,draw=red!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
            inner sep=0pt},>={Stealth},
        transition/.style={rectangle,draw=red!50,fill=cyan!40,thick,
            inner sep=2pt,node distance=0.5,minimum width=1.5cm,
            text depth=.1cm,
            text height=.3cm,
            minimum height=0.85cm,
            rounded corners}]
        %/      \node [circular,] {content};    
        \node[circular,node font=\Huge]     (addition)      {+};
                
        % node with dummy text
        \node [circular,minimum width=0.85,minimum height=0.85] (multiply1) [left= of addition] {\textcolor{blue!20}{Hello}};
        \path (multiply1.north west) edge[thick] (multiply1.south east);
        \path (multiply1.north east) edge[thick] (multiply1.south west);
        \node[rotate=90]        (layerscale)        [left=of multiply1]     {};
        \path (layerscale.south) ++(0,-0.2) node[rotate=90] {};
        
%       \node[transition]       (ffn)       [below=of multiply1]    {$ \eta $*\text{ADD}};
        \node[transition]       (ffn)       [below=of multiply1]    {$\eta  MHTA$};
        \node[transition]  (dummy2) [right=of ffn] {$\eta$} ;
        
         \draw [help lines] let \p1 = (ffn.base),
        \p2 = (dummy2.base),
        in (1.5,\y1) -- (-3,\y1)
        (1.5,\y2) -- (-3,\y2);
        
        \node[transition,baseline=(eta1.base)]          (eta1)      [below=of ffn]  {$\Omega(\cdot)$};
        \path (multiply1.east)      edge[post,thick]    (addition.west);
        \path (ffn.north)           edge[post,thick]    (multiply1.south);
        \path (eta1.north)          edge[post,thick]    (ffn.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Here is an ugly hack that produced the same effect in multiple nodes.
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {inner sep=0pt},transition/.style={rectangle,draw=red!50,fill=cyan!40,thick, inner sep=2pt,node distance=0.5,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.85cm,rounded corners}] 
\node (E) at (0,0) {}; \node (p) [right = 0pt of E,xshift=0.5cm] {MHTA}; \node[] (p1) at (p.center){}; \node (d) [right= -0.95cm of p1] {$\eta*$}; \draw[transition,opacity=0.5] (0,0) ++(0.05,-0.4)rectangle ++(1.6cm,0.85cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}


However, I wanted to achieve the same effect using a single node rather than multiple nodes.

Having text and math on different baselines is, let's say, quite unusual. Are you absolutely sure this won't irritate your readers?
